# Erro de compilação Maven plugin

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, tomcat

Utilizo os seguintes plugins pra compilar e rodar meu projeto web no IntelliJ IDEA:
**pom.xml**

```
//Código do pom.xml omitido
.
.
.
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
.
.
.

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>9090</port>
                    <path>/path</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
//Código do pom.xml omitido
```

e, às vezes fica retornando esses erros, quando eu rodo o Tomcat(`tomcat7:run`). Digo "às vezes" porque é somente às vezes mesmo, ai faço o build do projeto e executo, às vezes dá certo de cara, mas às vezes o erro persiste.

O erro, basicamente é `package javax.servlet.http does not exist`, mas a api de servlets está, com certeza, no projeto, já que às vezes dá certo e consigo rodar tranquilamente o projeto. Não entendo!!!

Segue o erro printado no console:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\.... "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=63077:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.5 tomcat7:run
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building bi-cnn 1.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ bi-cnn >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ bi-cnn ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ bi-cnn ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 176 source files to C:\Users\.....\target\classes

    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/..../src/main/java/br/com/...../login/ClasseDeControleHttp.java:[10,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/.../src/main/java/br/com/..../login/ControladorHttp.java:[6,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/.../src/main/java/.../login/ControladorHttp.java:[22,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class HttpSession
      location: class br.com......ControladorHttp
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/.../src/main/java/br/com/managedbeans/ManagedBean.java:[23,43] package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree does not exist
.
.
.
    [INFO] 39 errors 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 9.795 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-28T13:58:21-03:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/197M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project bi-cnn: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/.../src/main/java/br/com/.../Entidade.java:[10,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
.
.
.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Você informou a dependência `javax.servlet` no seu `pom.xml`?

Comment: sim sim, a dependência está lá, tanto que funciona às vezes sim, às vezes não.

Comment: Colocou o escopo como `provided` ?

Comment: editei o post com a dependência.

Comment: Rode o comando maven com -X na frente para rodar em nivel de debug, talvez exiba mais informações.